# Laravel 8: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my project and in this project, I have a table named `hostings` which it's migration goes here:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('hostings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

And now I want to return some results from the DB and show them on blade, so I added this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Hosting Name:</th>
        <td>{{ $hosting->name }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But now I get this error:

```
Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance
```

So what is going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

I would really appreciate if you share any idea or suggestion about this with me,

Thanks in advance.

**Controller code:**

```
public function index()
    {
        $hosting = Hosting::all();
        return view('admin.index', compact('hosting'));
    }
```

Comment: please share the controller code

Comment: @OMR Sorry, I just added it

Comment: Share your controller and also share your model code as well. I believe either you've not mentioned your fillables or you're not passing the correct values to the view.

Comment: @Hassaan Ali I just added the Controller question, plz check it out and thx

Comment: `Hosting::all` returns the array you've to use for loop to iterate through each item.

Comment: `collection instance` it means you have so many row you need to loop to get single value

Comment: if there is a single value in hosting then use the "first" instead of  "all"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you have collection you need to loop over it to get value

```php
<table>
    <tr>
        @foreach ($hosting as $host)
        <th>Hosting Name:</th>
        <td>{{ $host->name }}</td>
        @endforeach
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

else you can show all the host name in comma separated by this

```php
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Hosting Name:</th>
        <td>{{ $hosting->pluck('name')->join(',') }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

or you can get first data of collection like this

```php
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Hosting Name:</th>
        <td>{{ $hosting->first()->name }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ref
link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-join

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<table>
<tr>
   @foreach($hosting as $h)
    <th>Hosting Name:</th>
    <td>{{ $h->name }}</td>
   @endforeach
</tr>
```